# SQL - counting number of logins per day, per user

Tags: mysql, date, counting

I have a query that produces a table like the following:

```
Login_Date     Username
----------------------------------------------
1/1/10         user-1
1/1/10         user-1
1/1/10         user-2
1/2/10         user-1
1/2/10         user-2
1/3/10         user-1
1/3/10         user-1 
1/3/10         user-1
1/3/10         user-3
```

The query looks like the following:

```
SELECT Date_Used, Name AS licenseNames FROM B, A WHERE A.License_Key = B.License_Key  ORDER BY Date_Used ;
```

which is fine, but what I need it to produce, is a list of dates, where for every date it gives me a list of users that logged in that day, along with how many times they logged in. I've looked all over to try and find a concise solution to this, but It's been nothing but dead ends.

The result I want published would look like the following:

```
Login_Date    Username    # of Times logged in
--------------------------------------------------
1/1/10       user-1       2
1/1/10       user-2       1
1/2/10       user-1       1
1/2/10       user-2       2
1/3/10       user-1       3
1/3/10       user-3       1
```

Any help would be much appreciated, this is driving me insane.

**EDIT**

Here are the respective tables, to avoid confusion:

Table A Columns:

```
--------------------------
ID   License_Key    Name
```

Table B Columns:

```
------------------------------
ID    Date_Used     License_Key
```

**EDIT 2**

As per a comment request, all of the solutions thus far have provided the same result on the actual tables (although the SQL Fiddle works for all of them, so..?)

The results I'm getting are as follows:

```
Login_Date     UserName     Cnt (or NumLogins for the other solution)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
01-01-10       user-1        1
01-01-10       user-1        1
01-01-10       user-2        1
01-02-10       user-1        1
01-02-10       user-1        1
01-02-10       user-1        1
01-02-10       user-1        1
```

etc. etc. So it looks like the group by command in all of the answers thus far simply do.. nothing?? Very confusing...

Comment: You should group by username and date

Comment: why do you need the join?  I'm not sure IF A or B in your SQL is in reference to the table with, login_date, but if the other has multiple records in it for the same License_Key, you're counts will be off.

Comment: Added some info around the relevant columns/tables for clarity. The tables have more in them, but for the interest of brevity, I left them out (otherwise this would be a silly table structure indeed!)

Comment: is A-->B a 1-1 relationship or is it a M:1 or 1:M? to be safe, I think you have to get the count before you do the join.

Comment: A --> B is a 1:M, so.. each A can have multiple entries in B.

Comment: why in your original query you are selecting Date_Used and Name, but grouping by only Date_Used? Which value of Name do you want to get in case there are multiple names for the same date_used?

Comment: @fthiella sorry the group by was actually just a left-in typo from me trying some extra things, it did not affect the result in any way, removed in an edit.

Comment: @WillBD is Login_Date a DATE field, or is it a DATETIME? you can try to group by DATE(Login_Date)

Comment: @fthiella specifically it's a TIMESTAMP, actually

Comment: @fthiella Ohhhh! magic! that did it, you're the best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) query, with a COUNT(*) aggregated function. Since Date_Used is a DATETIME column, it can contain the DATE part but also the TIME part, so you have to extract just the DATE part using [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT
  DATE(Date_Used),
  Name AS licenseNames,
  COUNT(*) AS logins
FROM
  B INNER JOIN A
  ON A.License_Key = B.License_Key
GROUP BY
  DATE(Date_Used),
  Name
ORDER BY
  DATE(Date_Used),
  Name
```

Comment: Not sure why this received a down vote.  Looks good aside from the column names desired... and the potential issue with multiple values in 2nd table potentially causing inflated counts.

Comment: The downvote was because they just blopped a block of copy and paste code without explaining what they're doing.

Comment: accepted for being the first one to catch that DATE business. ALthough you have to change it in the 'Group By' not 'Order by' portion of the query for it to work properly, thanks again!

Comment: @WillBD thank you... oh yes, i forgot to change it also in the GROUP BY :) fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to implement here is the COUNT() aggregate function. You can use it with a GROUP BY statement, and it will count the number of rows that exist within your group.

In your case, you want to group by user and date. I also recommend you use a join instead:

```
SELECT date_used, name AS licenseNames, COUNT(*) AS numLogins
FROM B
JOIN A ON a.license_key = b.license_key
GROUP BY date_used, name
ORDER BY date_used;
```

**EDIT**

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39b07/1). The results look a little different form yours, but I think you made a mistake as user-2 only logged in once on 01/02/10 according to the table you have.

Comment: Due to the 1:M relationship this will artificially inflate the counts.

Comment: Indeed the user-2 being logged in twice was an error on my part. As far as the SQL... I put this identically into mine, but for some reason it won't group anything properly... investigating now (namely, it gives a single row per entry and just gives me a result with nothing but '1's in the numLogins column)

Comment: I really thought this should work, as all OP seems to want is to take his existing query, and get the count of logins per date per use which is what this does, doesn't it?

Comment: @WillBD Can you give an example in your question of the results you're getting vs what you'd expect?

Comment: @McAdam331 sure thing, edit made, and the expected value is what I see in the SQLFiddle. Which makes me inclined to believe that it's something about the nature of my tables blocking this operation, or the engine or.. something.

Comment: @WillBD What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @McAdam331 fthiella figured out why it wasn't working as expected, see the comments under the question for more info, you have to do Date() for a TIMESTAMP apparently. Thanks a million for all the help though!

Comment: OH! Well that changes everything, I had no idea it was a timestamp

Answer (score 1):

I used an inner join and a sub query to get the count before the join to deal with the 1:M relationship; otherwise the counts will artificially be inflated.

I used an aggregate function count(*) and a group by to get the count of license_keys used by date

```
SELECT B2.Date_used as Login_date, A.name as UserName, B2.Cnt
FROM A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT date_used, License_Key, count(*) cnt
FROM B
GROUP BY date_used, License_key) B2
ON A.License_key = B2.License_Key
```

I didn't alias the column name on count as I don't remember what mysql's escape character for columns is... ` or " or [... I can't remember.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with this query as I did with McAdam331's solution, for some reason, i'm just getting a count of '1' and the users listed multiple times per day, Because the solutions are working in SQLFiddle, I'm inclined to believe this is some quirk of InnoDB??

Comment: See comments under the other answers, this solution also works, but you do need to have a 'Date()' function around any TIMESTAMP or DATETIME fields for it to properly group, and therefore count. Thanks again! very thorough answer!